# Tensorflow - Split, Operate, then Sum 2D data point

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on a problem using tensorflow where I would like to apply the same tensor operation to all of the 1d pieces of data in a 2d data set, then sum the result of those operations together.

for example, let's say I have a data point:

```
x0 = [[1, 0, 1, 1],
      [0, 1, 1, 0],
      [1, 2, 0, 1],
      [0, 2, 2, 0]]
```

And a tensor operation (function might be a more accurate term) `f(x)`

I would like to do something like

```
y = sum([f(x) for x in x0]
```

I am having a bit of difficulty expressing this properly in TF. I think the closest I've gotten is below.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10, 10])

x_sub = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

W1 = weight_variable([10, 10])
b1= bias_variable([10])

l1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x_sub, W1) + b1)

Wf = weight_variable([10, 1])
bf = bias_variable([1])

y_sub = tf.matmul(l1, Wf) + bf

y = ? # I would like to split/unstack x here, apply y_sub to each
      # tensor resulting from the split (shaped [None, 10]) and then
      # add the results together

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1]) 

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.mean_squared_error(y_, y))
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, it seems you want to perform batched matrix multiplications and additions (multiplications, resp. additions, of the batch of elements in `x` stacked over the 1st dimension, with `W1` then `Wf`, resp. with `b1` then `bf`).

This can be done directly with some manual or automatic broadcasting:

```python
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10, 10])
x_shape = tf.shape(x)

W1 = weight_variable([10, 10])
b1 = bias_variable([10])

# We broadcast W1 into a tensor of shape (None, 10, 10), for performed batched matmul:
W1_exp = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(W1, 0), (x_shape[0], 1, 1))
l = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, W1_exp) + b1)
# note: broadcasting is straightforward and covered for the addition with b1

Wf = weight_variable([10, 1])
bf = bias_variable([1])

# Similarly, we broadcast Wf beforehand:
Wf_exp = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(Wf, 0), (x_shape[0], 1, 1))
y = tf.matmul(l, Wf_exp) + bf

# Summing over the dimension #1:
y = tf.reduce_sum(y, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function that does exactly what you want: [`tf.foldl`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/foldl).

The first argument of `tf.foldl` is a function `fn`. **This is not your function `f`**. Rather, it's a function that combines both your `f` and the sum that you want to perform. In other words, if you have a function `f` that operates on a single tensor, then you can define `fn` as:

```
fn=lambda acc,x: acc+f(x)
```

in this lambda expression, `acc` represents the current accumulated sum of all rows, and `x` represents the current row. Thus, what `fn` does in this case is to apply `f` on the current row and to add the results to the accumulated sum.

The next argument to `tf.foldl` is just the tensor to which you want to apply these functions.

For example, let's assume that `f` is just a squaring function. Then:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x0 = tf.constant([[1, 0, 1, 1],
      [0, 1, 1, 0],
      [1, 2, 0, 1],
      [0, 2, 2, 0]])
f = lambda u: tf.square(u)

fn = lambda acc,x: acc+f(x)
y = tf.foldl(fn,x0)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(y) # output is [2,9,6,2]
```

Another argument for `tf.foldl` which you may need is `initializer`, which initializes the accumulation, to the right value and shape. This is required if your function `f` changes the size of each row. Here is an example:

```
x0 = tf.constant([[1, 0, 1, 1],
      [0, 1, 1, 0],
      [1, 2, 0, 1],
      [0, 2, 2, 0]])
f = lambda u: tf.concat([u,u],0)

fn = lambda acc,x: acc+f(x)
initializer = tf.constant([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
y = tf.foldl(fn,x0,initializer)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(y) # output is  [2, 5, 4, 2, 2, 5, 4, 2]
```